Couple a signal onto another one SystemVerilog
I have a circuit that has 2 ports, A and B, connected through a switch. I want to couple only the signal that's on A port to another port C. I don't want B port to couple on C. This is what I have:
module SignalArrivalDetector
(
    inout wire [31:0] A,
    inout wire [31:0] B,
    output wire [31:0] C
 
);

logic [31:0] A_INT;    
logic EN_INT = 1'b1;
tranif1 a [$bits(A)-1:0] (A, B, {$bits(A){EN_INT}});

always @(A)
  begin
    EN_INT = 1'b0;
    eval();
    EN_INT = 1'b1;
  end

task eval();
    A_INT= A;
endtask

nmos b [$bits(A)-1:0] (C, A, {$bits(A){A_INT}});
  
endmodule

In this code, I am isolating the 2 ports A and B so that I can monitor changes on A and put it on A_INT and use it as enable for my nmos primitive.  I am afraid I will get changes from B side also on A since EN_INT is 1 and I am setting it to 0 later in the always block.  Do I need any delays here?  Or, Is there any other way of doing it?

@toolic I have modified the code, it should have A_INT instead of {$bits(A){A_INT}}. I just want to achieve just coupling C on A. I am unable to think of any other way to do this. I am using always block to disconnect A and B.

Please do not modify the question after an answer is posted because it invalidates the answer.

As my answer states, you need to rethink this design completely.

You using mos primitives, we need to see all the drivers on your wires to see if you’re using them correctly.

@KatrinaMarrie: Please undelete your follow-up question because it is on-topic.  I posted an answer to it, and you should not get into the habit of deleting questions after they receive answers, as you did with this question as well.

@KatrinaMarrie - Hi, As commented above by toolic, please don't routinely delete your questions after receiving an answer. Although the site allowed you to do those deletions, there are very few valid reasons to do it. || As it says here: "If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time." TY

The following line does not comply with the IEEE Std 1800-2023:
nmos b [$bits(A)-1:0] (C, A, {$bits(A){A_INT}});

Expression [$bits(A)-1:0] resolves to 32 bits, but expression {$bits(A){A_INT}} resolves to 1024 bits.  This mismatch should generate a compile error with your simulator.  If it does not, you should consider using another simulator.
The code is difficult to understand.  Since there are no delays and there is a bidirectional switch (tranif1), and the switch control depends on feedback from the always block,  I suspect the code may have simulation race conditions.  Races lead to unpredictable simulation results and should be avoided.
I recommend re-designing the module.  It might simplify things to have the module ports be 1-bit signals instead of 32 bits wide, then place 32 instances of the module.
